# "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" while writing XML

Tags: c#, xml

I am currently trying to create some code to append to my XML file, it will first check if the file is created and if it is; it will then open the file ready for appending.

But the problem is, is that I am getting the above error message on the last line. If I put existingFile.Close() before this line, the error goes away; but then the data does not append.

Could someone please help me.

I can give the entire code if anyone wishes, but I just though I would give the bit that is giving my an error for now.

Code

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(FullPath))
{
    found = true;
    System.IO.FileStream existingFile = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(FullPath);                    
    existingFile.Seek(-endtag.Length, System.IO.SeekOrigin.End);                   
    writer = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(FullPath, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Comment: Why are you keeping the file open after you have written to it? Would it solve the issue if you close it after every write and open it with the Append flag instead?

Comment: Your primary problem is that you're passing `FullPath` (the file name) to the `XmlTextWriter` constructor, when I think you want to pass `existingFile` (the stream). That will probably make the code work, but you're going to end up with invalid XML.

Comment: On second thought, this is an interesting idea: seeking back past the end tag. You'll have to be sure that your `XmlTextWriter` doesn't try to add the xml header, but if you do that then this just could possibly work.

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Comment: You should really show more of your code. In particular, it's hard to guess the scope of `writer`.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works, but with a few cautions.

First, it assumes that there aren't any newlines between elements. That is, the XML is like:

```
<RootNode><Element></Element></RootNode>
```

Rather than

```
<RootNode>
  <Element>
  </Element>
</RootNode>
```

If you have indented XML with newlines and such, then when you subtract the length of the root node, you'll have to subtract for the newline, as well. If you want this to work in the general case, you'll also have to check for trailing white space. But if you know that the last character of the file is the `>` in the end tag, then the code below should work.

I'm a little disappointed that I have to close the file and then call `File.AppendText` to add the end tag, but I couldn't think of a better way. Shouldn't be a big problem unless you're hitting this thing a lot.

```
    private const string EndTag = "</RootNode>";

    private void AppendXmlFile()
    {
        using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(XmlFilename))
        {
            fs.Seek(-EndTag.Length, SeekOrigin.End);
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings {OmitXmlDeclaration = true};
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(fs, settings))
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("xyzzy");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("magic", "plugh");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }
        // Now write the end tag
        File.AppendAllText(XmlFilename, EndTag);
    }
```

Note here that I tell the `XmlWriter` to omit the XML declaration. Otherwise, you end up with a new XML header (i.e. `<?xml ...>`) being inserted.

By the way, I used [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than [XmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx). As the documentation for `XmlTextWriter` says:

> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, we recommend that you use the System.Xml.XmlWriter class instead.

I find it to be a cleaner and easier to use interface.